# Python - Ask for input, extract data from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python (2nd) day and working on a problem that asks me to Write a program that reads ASCII files (asks for file name as input), checks if it has more than
two words and prints out the two first words of the file on screen.

Its a little vague but I am going to assume the file is all str, deliminiated by spaces.

ex.

```
text1 text2 text text text
```

So far I have:

```
name = (raw_input("Please enter the name of the file: "))
f=open(name)
with codecs.open(name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip(BOM)
words=line.split()
print words
if len(words) > 2:
    print 'There are more than two words'
    firsttow = words[:2]
    print firstrow
```

I am having problems writing the else statement, I want to have,

```
if len(words) > 2:
    print 'There are more than two words'
    firsttow = words[:2]
print firstrow
else: 
if len(words) <2:
        print 'There are under 2 words, no words will be shown'
```

How should this be added and is there any other ways to improve my code for this questions?
I really appreciate the help

Thanks in advance

*Edit: Thanks for all the help, the last problem I had was when i run .py file, I want to be able to see the results before the cmd window closes.

Adding: `raw_input("Press return to close this window...")` does notwork and it closes right away. Any ideas?

Edit2* This is my current code, still trying to work on having the cmd window open after

```
import codecs
BOM = codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode('utf8')
name = (raw_input("Please enter the name of the file: "))

with codecs.open(name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    words=[]            #define words here
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip(BOM)
        words.extend(line.split())        #append words from each line to words  

if len(words) > 2:
    print 'There are more than two words'
    firstrow = words[:2]
    print firstrow                #indentation problem here
elif len(words) <2:                    #use if
    print 'There are under 2 words, no words will be shown'

raw_input("Press return to close this window...")
```

Comment: Note: You are actually opening the file twice for no reason. And due to the `for` loop you will only look at the file's last line.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the extra open

Comment: @MatthewLiem where did you placed the `raw_input("Press return to close this window...")`?

Answer (score 1):

That code should be written as:

```
if len(words) > 2:
    print 'There are more than two words'
    firsttow = words[:2]
    print firstrow
elif len(words) <2:
    print 'There are under 2 words, no words will be shown'
```

Note the indentation, and the use of `elif` (which means "else if").

Comment: AHHH thats the problem, it was my indentation..was stuck on why my else or elif would never work. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
with codecs.open(name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    words=[]            #define words here
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip(BOM)
        words.extend(line.split())        #append words from each line to words      

if len(words) > 2:
    print 'There are more than two words'
    firsttow = words[:2]
    print firstrow                #indentation problem here
if len(words) <2:                    #use if
    print 'There are under 2 words, no words will be shown'
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason you use another if rather than else?

Comment: @MatthewLiem both will work fine, but using `elif` here makes more sense.